# How can I get the embed field title and value in the same line

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I am trying to create an `embed` using my `discord bot`, but unfortunately, I don't know how to make the `title` of a field be in the **same line** as its `value`

This is my code so far:

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client()

client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

client.on("message", message => {
    if(message.content === "hy!help") {
        const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setColor('#ff0000')
            .setTitle('`General Rules`')
            .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833945466550878246/838524255057608734/1619990134900.png')
            .addFields(
                { name: '`1`', value:'Some value here' },
                { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
                { name: 'Inline field title', value: 'Some value here', inline: true },
            )
            .setFooter('© By Cowboy RolePlay', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833945466550878246/838524255057608734/1619990134900.png');
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
        }  } )
client.login('token')
```

Comment: Step one is to identify what programming language you're working in. Java and Javascript are *unrelated* languages.

Comment: Have you already looked at  [this guide](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embed-preview)?

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is not possible, because discord does not allow name and value in the same line. Fields are basically columns (max number of these columns is 3 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgJ9z.png))
You can do this with `.setDescription` [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbJw9.png):

```
client.on("message", message => {
if(message.content === "hy!help") {
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('#ff0000')
        .setTitle('`General Rules`')
        .setThumbnail('https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833945466550878246/838524255057608734/1619990134900.png')
        .setDescription('**Name:** value \n **Name:** value \n **Name:** value '
        .setFooter('© By Cowboy RolePlay', 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/833945466550878246/838524255057608734/1619990134900.png');
message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
    }
```